# LESS Mixins not available

Tags: css, less

in my current project ive the following structure in the index from icnludes:

...

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/master.less" media="screen" />

<!--module source CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" type="text/css" href="module/A/css/A.less" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="module/B/css/B.less" media="screen" />
```

...

in my master.less i include other less files like the mixin.less. in this file i have a lot of declaration which works fine - tested.

but if i try to use some mixins like .gradient in my module B.less i become a error like this:
.gradient is undefined

the gradient mixin which is placed in the mixin.less is totaly okay:

```
.gradient (@startColor: white, @endColor: #eee) {
    background-color: @startColor;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@startColor), to(@endColor));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor);
}
```

when i use this mixin directly in my B.less it works. so im confused about. im using the client side part with the less.js and have read the fkn manual on http://lesscss.org/ but i dont know whats wrong.

the files are loaded correctly etc whats wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the LESS files in your HTML document gets compiled **independently**, so any mixins that you're creating in master.less are staying withing context of this file only, and are not visible to the other .less files.

I would suggest you do this:

1. Create a file mixins.less with all your mixins,
2. In your master.less, import that mixins.less file **first**, and then import any additional module less files,
3. In your HTML document, reference master.less only.

I agree that the situation you're experiencing isn't clearly defined in the documentation, but I am assuming that most people who want to play with LESS using less.js start with just one file.

Hope this helps.